# Compilation of 2.6.35 Linux + Android patches. Physical address of the kernel image?

Tags: android, linux, compilation

As the title says I'm compiling a linux kernel with android patches. I'm being asked a few configuration questions as this is my first time compiling. I was asked the following question:

```
Physical address of the decompressed kernel_image (ZRELADDR) [] (NEW)
```

I don't know what they are are asking. I think its odd to be asking for a specific address in memory. Any one familiar with this?

Some updated info: 
The source of this question is arch/arm/Kconfig

I found Google's recommended config here: 
http://source.android.com/devices/tech/kernel.html

I'm trying to make a connection now between the two now. Guess I need to read up on how .config files work

Comment: You may have a much easier time starting with a kernel config from something similar - either pulling /proc/config.gz off the device if it already has a version of Android you are replacing, or cribbing a default config from a similar architecture device for which there's a working AOSP, "community ROM", or eval board vendor kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get through this issue. It turns out the previous question was asking if you wanted the decompressed kernel image address auto-calculated which I had said 'no' to(this was the default). I still can't imagine a situation where you would want to manually specify the address of a kernel image though & now I'm wondering if skipping this question is the right thing to do as the default is to have you answer it.